# Set a variable as Property vba

Tags: vba

Hello i am trying to figure out how to define a variable as a property I will write some code to show what i mean.

Thank you

```
'i want to call the Selection.ShapeRange.Width

Set img = Selection.ShapeRange ' -- Looks Ok here
img.width = 200 ' -- Works good 

set largo = img.width

largo = 200  ' Here the selected image should be enlarged to 200px Crash :(
```

Comment: `largo = img.Width` - drop the `Set`, that's for assigning object references. Note that assigning `largo` will not assign to `img.Width`, because `largo` is just a local variable holding an integer value, it's not "linked" in any way to the `Width` property (and cannot be).

Comment: Curious what the error is though. `Set largo = img.width` is where execution should stop, because `largo` isn't an object, so `Set` is illegal. (is `largo` declared?)

Comment: Thank you Mathieu It seems right but the thing i want to do with "largo = 200 " is to enlarge the selected shape to 200px, not to get the selected shape's current width.
`largo = img.width` automatically takes largo as a variable and fills it with a number.

i want that `largo = 200` mean  `Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 200`

Comment: Why not make `img.width = largo` instead? Where`largo` holds the value you want to increase by...

Comment: Good point, i have been doing it like that. But the tricky part is that i want to replace the sentences because when a shape is in rotation (image as shape) the width becomes the height and vice versa and it is a very complex running so i wanrted to switch the width and height name for me to be more sintax friendly

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include this rather critically important piece of info ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you have [two values you want to swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936943/set-a-variable-as-property-vba/57937774#comment102290864_57936943) (here the `Height` and `Width` property values of a `Shape`), all you need is a variable to hold one of the values:

```
Dim originalHeight As Double
originalHeight = img.Height
```

Then you can proceed with the swap, starting with the property you temporarily stored in a local variable:

```
img.Height = img.Width
img.Width = originalHeight
```